# Problemas com a Midaslib

Tags: delphi, dll

Estou tentando executar uma aplicação em Delphi, porém toda vez que tento compilar aparece um erro "Unit 'Midaslib' not found", existe alguma forma de colocar essa biblioteca manualmente?

Verifiquei que antigamente utilizava-se o midas.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o diretório onde se encontra o arquivo MidasLib.pas não está na *Library* do Delphi.
Geralmente é: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\source\data\dsnap`
Deve funcionar a partir do **Delphi 6**.

Comment: Na verdade o nome do projeto não é midaslib, aparentemente Midaslib é uma biblioteca e por isso não estou conseguindo, pois ela não consta nessa versão do Delphi, algo assim.Estou utilizando a versão Tókio 10.2.

Comment: Sei que o nome do seu projeto não é *MidasLib*. *MidasLib* realmente é apenas uma biblioteca, e como mencionei na resposta, o caminho onde está essa biblioteca é que não deve estar adicionado na **Library** do Delphi. Podes conferir?

Answer (score 1):

Na classe principal, declare na unit o `MidasLib` não vai mais alertar sobre a dll.

Comment: Eu estou declarando na unit e mesmo assim aparece o erro.

Comment: @FlávioNavesJr tente colocar o midas.dll na pasta do projeto e na pasta System32 ou SysWOW64

Comment: @FlávioNavesJr Se está dando erro na hora que você declara o MidasLib na unit, deve ser pelo motivo que nosso amigo Andrey mencionou, está faltando declarar o MidasLib na biblioteca

Answer (score 0):

Mas é  no seu computador ou num computador cliente?
O que normalmente se faz é ter que colocar o

```
  uses
     midas,
     midaslib,
```

no codigo do projecto (ficheiro .dpr do seu projecto). Pode lá chegar ao clicar no nome do projecto e fazer *View Source*.